# Spring List Binding

Tags: forms, spring, list

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have the following object association in my model:

```
public class Contract {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   //getters/setters...
}

public class User {
   ....
   private List<Contract> contracts;
   ....
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(....)
public String getUser(@PathVariable Integer userId, Model model) {
   ....
   model.addAttribute(userDao.findUser(userId));
   model.addAttribute("contractsList", contractDao.findAllContracts());
   ....
}

@RequestMapping(....)
public String processUser(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
   ....

   //Create a copy of the user to update...
   User userToUpdate = userDao.findUser(user.getId);

   ....
   userToUpdate.setContracts(user.getContracts());
   //set other properties...

   userDao.updateUser(userToUpdate);

   return "someSuccessView";
} 

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
   binder.registerCustomEditor(Contract.class, new UserContractsPropertyEditor());
}
```

My PropertyEditor:

```
public class UserContractsPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

   @Inject ContractDao contractDao;

   @Override
   public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      System.out.println("matching value: " + text);
      if (text != "") {
         Integer contractId = new Integer(text);
         super.setValue(contractDao.findContract(contractId));
      } 
   }

}
```

My JSP form:

```
<form:form commandName="user"> 
   <%-- Other fields... --%>
   <form:checkboxes items="${contractsList}" 
      path="contracts" 
      itemValue="id" 
      itemLabel="name" />   
</form:form>
```

The form renders correctly. That is, the checkbox list of Contracts is generated and the correct ones are "checked." The problem is when I submit I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'items' must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractMultiCheckedElementTag.setItems(AbstractMultiCheckedElementTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp._005fn.forms.user_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fcheckboxes_005f0(user_jsp.java:1192)
    ....
```

The custom property editor seems to be doing its job and there are no null/empty strings being passed.

If the form and controller makes the conversion when viewing the form, why is it having trouble when processing the form? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that a call to getContract() returns a List instance:

```
public List<Contract> getContracts() {
    if (contracts == null) contracts = new ArrayList<Contract>();
    return contracts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. I guess a fresh set of eyes first thing in the morning does the trick again.

Apparently, my custom property editor had no clue what to do with the id value I was passing in since it couldn't access my DAO/service. So, I had to change the constructor:

```
public class UserContractsPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

   private ContractDao contractDao;

   public UserContractsPropertyEditor(ContractDao contractDao) {
      this.contractDao = contractDao;
   }

   @Override
   public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      Integer contractId = new Integer(text);
      Contract contract = contractDao.findContract(contractId);
      super.setValue(contract);
   }

}
```

Then, modified the initBinder in my controller:

```
   @Inject ContractDao contractDao;
   ....    
   @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
       binder.registerCustomEditor(Contract.class, new UserContractsPropertyEditor(this.contractDao));
    }
```

Maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: In case you are still active: I pretty much copied your (corrected) example and getting error 400. What is wrong?